# Symmetric algebra and exact sequences

Tags: ring-theory, modules, exact-sequence, symmetric-algebra

Suppose that we have a commutative ring $R$ and an exact sequence of graded R-modules
$$0\rightarrow M'\rightarrow M\rightarrow M''\rightarrow 0$$
It is true that we have an exact sequence of graded R-modules
$$0\rightarrow\text{S}^{\bullet}(M')\rightarrow\text{S}^{\bullet}(M)\rightarrow\text{S}^{\bullet}(M'')\rightarrow 0$$
where $\text{S}^{\bullet}(-)$ denotes the symmetric algebra?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Take $R$ to be a field and the modules to be f.d. vector spaces concentrated in degree $1$. You’ll see that exactness is already impossible in degree $2$ by a dimension count, and also in degree $0$. What is true in the field case is that the Poincare series of the left and right multiply to the Poincare series of the middle (rather than adding).